# Android studio - how can I change the color of action bar

Tags: android, android-studio

I've searched on google on to change the color, but every code that I see doenst work for me. I mean the color doesnt change. I can change the style. Here is one of the code that I tried:

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#C1000E</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#E5ED0E</item>
</style>
```

I've seen this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#AdvancedStyles
and this too: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html
And nothing changes the color.

Comment: instead of `@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar` try `android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML code works on my side. I only changed `AppBaseTheme` to `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light` in your `AppTheme` definition because you didn't provide `AppBaseTheme` definition.

Is your `AppBaseTheme` a child of `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light`? Or any other Android Theme.

Comment: I myself mainly look at examples on GitHub and questions on SO. The Android Dev website also has a couple good examples.